# Highlight TreeView item being dragged over

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, treeview

In my application, I have a TreeView that allows drag/drop.  I have all the functionality working fine, however I am having difficulty highlighting a TreeViewItem when it is dragged over.   Here is my style for my treeview item.  The IsMouseOver trigger does not work while dragging, because dragging seems to block other mouse events.  Can anyone help me trigger the same border changes on my treeview item while dragging?

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"> 
    <Setter Property="Template"> 
        <Setter.Value> 
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"> 
                <Grid> 
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/> 
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> 
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> 
                        <RowDefinition/> 
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                    <ToggleButton  
                        x:Name="PART_Expander" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        ClickMode="Press" 
                        /> 
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="OuterBorder"  
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        BorderThickness="1"  
                        CornerRadius="3"  
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"  
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        > 
                        <Border  
                            x:Name="InnerBorder"  
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            BorderThickness="1"  
                            CornerRadius="2"  
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"  
                            Background="Transparent" 
                            > 
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                x:Name="PART_Content" 
                                ContentSource="Header" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                /> 
                        </Border> 
                    </Border> 
                    <ItemsPresenter 
                        x:Name="PART_ItemsHost" 
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        /> 
                </Grid> 
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" SourceName="OuterBorder" Value="True"> 
                        <Setter TargetName="OuterBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" /> 
                        <Setter TargetName="OuterBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red" /> 
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" /> 
                    </Trigger> 
                    <MultiTrigger> 
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
            </ControlTemplate> 
        </Setter.Value> 
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using an attached property for this, and then use that property in my xaml file to change the background color of the tree view item:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SKNotes.Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements an attached property used for styling TreeViewItems when
    /// they're a possible drop target.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TreeViewDropHighlighter
    {
        #region private variables
        /// <summary>
        /// the TreeViewItem that is the current drop target
        /// </summary>
        private static TreeViewItem _currentItem = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether the current TreeViewItem is a possible
        /// drop target
        /// </summary>
        private static bool _dropPossible;
        #endregion

        #region IsPossibleDropTarget
        /// <summary>
        /// Property key (since this is a read-only DP) for the IsPossibleDropTarget property.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsPossibleDropTargetKey = 
                                    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
                                        "IsPossibleDropTarget",
                                        typeof( bool ),
                                        typeof( TreeViewDropHighlighter ),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( null,
                                            new CoerceValueCallback( CalculateIsPossibleDropTarget ) ) );


        /// <summary>
        /// Dependency Property IsPossibleDropTarget.
        /// Is true if the TreeViewItem is a possible drop target (i.e., if it would receive
        /// the OnDrop event if the mouse button is released right now).
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPossibleDropTargetProperty = IsPossibleDropTargetKey.DependencyProperty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Getter for IsPossibleDropTarget
        /// </summary>
        public static bool GetIsPossibleDropTarget( DependencyObject obj )
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Coercion method which calculates the IsPossibleDropTarget property.
        /// </summary>
        private static object CalculateIsPossibleDropTarget( DependencyObject item, object value )
        {
            if ( ( item == _currentItem ) && ( _dropPossible ) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the <see cref="TreeViewDropHighlighter"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        static TreeViewDropHighlighter( )
        {
            // Get all drag enter/leave events for TreeViewItem.
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof( TreeViewItem ),
                                      TreeViewItem.PreviewDragEnterEvent,
                                      new DragEventHandler( OnDragEvent ), true );
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof( TreeViewItem ),
                                      TreeViewItem.PreviewDragLeaveEvent,
                                      new DragEventHandler( OnDragLeave ), true );
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof( TreeViewItem ),
                                      TreeViewItem.PreviewDragOverEvent,
                                      new DragEventHandler( OnDragEvent ), true );
        }

        #region event handlers
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when an item is dragged over the TreeViewItem.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="args">The <see cref="System.Windows.DragEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        static void OnDragEvent( object sender, DragEventArgs args )
        {
            lock ( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty )
            {
                _dropPossible = false;

                if ( _currentItem != null )
                {
                    // Tell the item that previously had the mouse that it no longer does.
                    DependencyObject oldItem = _currentItem;
                    _currentItem = null;
                    oldItem.InvalidateProperty( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty );
                }

                if ( args.Effects != DragDropEffects.None )
                {
                    _dropPossible = true;
                }

                TreeViewItem tvi = sender as TreeViewItem;
                if ( tvi != null )
                {
                    _currentItem = tvi;
                    // Tell that item to re-calculate the IsPossibleDropTarget property
                    _currentItem.InvalidateProperty( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty );
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the drag cursor leaves the TreeViewItem
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="args">The <see cref="System.Windows.DragEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        static void OnDragLeave( object sender, DragEventArgs args )
        {
            lock ( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty )
            {
                _dropPossible = false;

                if ( _currentItem != null )
                {
                    // Tell the item that previously had the mouse that it no longer does.
                    DependencyObject oldItem = _currentItem;
                    _currentItem = null;
                    oldItem.InvalidateProperty( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty );
                }

                TreeViewItem tvi = sender as TreeViewItem;
                if ( tvi != null )
                {
                    _currentItem = tvi;
                    tvi.InvalidateProperty( IsPossibleDropTargetProperty );
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

and then in the xaml file:

```
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="utils:TreeViewDropHighlighter.IsPossibleDropTarget" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed today.  Thanks so much Stefan!  In my treeview I noticed though that sometimes it wouldn't automatically remove the highlight from my drop, so I registered the drop event and wrote a simple function that sets _dropPossible back to false and Invalidates IsPossibleDropTargetProperty.  Maybe useful to somebody else?

Comment: Great work!  One thing that I added in addition to what #chocojosh added, is telling the TreeViewItem to expand if it has items on the OnDragEvent event.  You can do this by adding: 
     if (_currentItem.HasItems)
          _currentItem.IsExpanded = true;

Comment: The code works very well, except the target item background was still in `HighlightBrushKey` when mouse drag had been released.

Comment: Hi @Dia I noticed the same issue when I was using this code.  Did you find a way to get the target items background back to normal when mouse drag has been released?

Comment: @Stavros Try add one line in `TreeViewDropHighlighter()` constructor `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem),
                TreeViewItem.PreviewDropEvent,
                new DragEventHandler(OnDragDrop), true);`

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [DragOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.dragover.aspx) event (and possibly DragEnter/DragLeave) instead of IsMouseOver.

Comment: "DragOver" is not a valid property to set a trigger in the the same fashion as "IsMouseOver".  I can use an EventTrigger, however they seem to only accept StoryBoards and I cannot figure out how to set my border properties within a StoryBoard the same way I did for the IsMouseOver Setters.

Comment: I had to add one line to TreeViewDropHighlighter() constructor, to also remove the changes after a drop was done....

EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), TreeViewItem.PreviewDropEvent, new DragEventHandler(OnDragLeave), true);

Comment: It's an event. Sorry that wasn't clear! You can use an event setter in your style to add it to all your tree view items.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Stefan's answer, I found that is necessary to add also the Drop event:

```
static void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    lock (IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
    {
        _dropPossible = false;

        if (_currentItem != null)
        {
            _currentItem.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty);
        }

        TreeViewItem tvi = sender as TreeViewItem;
        if (tvi != null)
        {
            tvi.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

and registering drop event also:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem),
             TreeViewItem.PreviewDropEvent,
             new DragEventHandler(OnDragDrop), true);
```

Otherwise if drop occurs of one treeItem over another, the background might not change. Same thing if you press ESC.

Answer (score 1):

This post is simply a porting of Stefan's awesome response above to VB, for those of us working in those confines; I have nothing to offer except to hope I didn't screw anything up too badly. It appears to work for me:

```
Namespace SKNotes.Utilities

''' <summary>
''' Implements an attached property used for styling TreeViewItems when
''' they are a possible drop target.
''' </summary>
Public Class TreeViewDropHighlighter

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The TreeViewItem that is the current drop target
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared _CurrentItem As TreeViewItem = Nothing

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates whether the current TreeView Item is a possible drop target
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Shared _DropPossible As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Property Key (since this is a read only DP) for the IsPossibleDropTarget property.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Shared ReadOnly IsPossibleDropTargetKey As DependencyPropertyKey = _
                                            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly _
                                            ( _
                                                "IsPossibleDropTarget", _
                                                GetType(Boolean), _
                                                GetType(TreeViewDropHighlighter), _
                                                New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, _
                                                                                New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf CalculateIsPossibleDropTarget)
                                                                                )
                                            )
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Dependency Property IsPossibleDropTarget.
    ''' Is true if the TreeViewItem is a possible drop target (ie, if it would receive the 
    ''' OnDrop even if the mouse button is release right now).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared ReadOnly IsPossibleDropTargetProperty As DependencyProperty = IsPossibleDropTargetKey.DependencyProperty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Getter for IsPossibleDropTarget
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function GetIsPossibleDropTarget(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As Boolean
        Return CBool(obj.GetValue(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Coercion method which calculates the IsPossibleDropTarget property
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Function CalculateIsPossibleDropTarget(item As DependencyObject, value As Object) As Object
        If item.Equals(_CurrentItem) And _
           _DropPossible Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes the TreeViewDropHighlighter class
    ''' </summary>
    Shared Sub New()
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(GetType(TreeViewItem), _
                                            TreeViewItem.PreviewDragEnterEvent, _
                                            New DragEventHandler(AddressOf OnDragEvent), True)
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(GetType(TreeViewItem), _
                                            TreeViewItem.PreviewDragLeaveEvent,
                                            New DragEventHandler(AddressOf OnDragLeave), True)
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(GetType(TreeViewItem), _
                                            TreeViewItem.PreviewDragOverEvent, _
                                            New DragEventHandler(AddressOf OnDragEvent), True)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Called when an item is dragged over the TreeView Item
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    ''' <param name="args">The System.Windows.DragEventArgs instance containing the event data</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Shared Sub OnDragEvent(sender As Object, args As DragEventArgs)
        SyncLock (IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            _DropPossible = False
            If Not IsNothing(_CurrentItem) Then
                'Tell the item that previously had the mouse that it no longer does.
                Dim OldItem As DependencyObject = _CurrentItem
                _CurrentItem = Nothing
                OldItem.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            End If

            If args.Effects <> DragDropEffects.None Then
                _DropPossible = True
            End If

            Dim tvi As TreeViewItem = CType(sender, TreeViewItem)
            If Not IsNothing(tvi) Then
                _CurrentItem = tvi
                'Tell that item to recalculate the IsPossibleDropTarget property
                _CurrentItem.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Shared Sub OnDragLeave(sender As Object, args As DragEventArgs)

        SyncLock (IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            _DropPossible = False
            If Not IsNothing(_CurrentItem) Then
                'Tell the item that previously had the mouse that it no longer does
                Dim OldItem As DependencyObject = _CurrentItem
                _CurrentItem = Nothing
                OldItem.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            End If

            Dim tvi As TreeViewItem = CType(sender, TreeViewItem)
            If Not IsNothing(tvi) Then
                _CurrentItem = tvi
                tvi.InvalidateProperty(IsPossibleDropTargetProperty)
            End If

        End SyncLock

    End Sub

End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Thanks dansan, it works perfectly! We VB guys are a dying breed and need to stick together!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Stefan's answer and the fix proposed by @XMight this is how you can achieve a nice delayed auto-expand of a TreeViewItem node:

```
private static DateTime _lastDragLeaveTime; 

static void OnDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    .....    
    if (sender is TreeViewItem tvi)
    {       
        _lastDragLeaveTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Then on drag event you check if you stayed more than 0.5 seconds over this new node and expand it if it has children:

```
static void OnDragEvent(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    .....    
    if (sender is TreeViewItem tvi)
    {
        .....
        TimeSpan hoverTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastDragLeaveTime);
        if (hoverTime.TotalSeconds > 0.5)
        {
            if (_currentItem.HasItems && !_currentItem.IsSelected)
            {
                _currentItem.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**!_currentItem.IsSelected** is required to prevent auto expanding the current dragged node.